# Installing local gem from Dockerfile does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems

I'm trying to install a self-made local Ruby gem in a dockerized Rails app. This is from my `Dockerfile.dev`:

```
RUN gem install --local /var/workdir/gems/my_gem-0.1.0.gem
```

However, building the container does not work:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem '/var/workdir/gems/my_gem-0.1.0.gem' (>=0) in any repository
```

The gem is at this place, and when I remove the line from the Dockerfile, start the container and open a terminal inside it, I can run `gem install --local` and install the gem.

What's wrong with my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you try to copy your gem from your computer to the container you'll get the job done.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy